# Korean food as countable or not countable

Tags: word-choice, word-request

"food" is sometimes countable and sometimes not.  so, I don't know whether I can say like these:

A:Where can I buy Korean food?

B1:You can find it on the second floor.

B2:You can find some on the second floor.

Is it possible to answer A like B1 and B2? If it's possible, what differences are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine. *B1* suggests that there is Korean food only on the second floor and nowhere else. *B2* suggests that there is Korean food on multiple floors and that only some of it is on the second floor.

Comment: I disagree. B1 suggests that the second floor is the department specialising in Korean food, and is the most natural-sounding way of giving directions in a large store. B2 is much less idiomatic; it might imply 'We do stock _some_ Korean ingredients, but not many.'

Comment: Fair points. Being in Southern California, I didn't even see this as being an aisle in a supermarket, but rather Korean food in an Asian food court (there are many here). In B2, I saw 
"Korean food" as different food carts, some of which are on the second floor. The singular "it" in B1 is "Korean food," which I think implies "all of it," not "some of it."

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of a food court, as I've never seen a multi-storey one here in the UK.

Comment: Likewise, I don't know that I've ever been to a supermarket so big that it had a "Korean aisle." But being Korean myself, I think it would be a great thing.